# What is the difference between opts and options in Elixir Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.http?

Tags: elixir, cowboy

The function is defined as

```
def http(plug, opts, options \\ []) do
...
```

Why are there two arguments that appear to mean the same thing but have different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first options are the plug options. The second options are the ones given to cowboy and ranch. We should definitely rename them to make it clearer.

Comment: Btw, a pull request is appreciated. :)

Comment: Pull request submitted.